# gtsummary tbl_regression() on gls object

Tags: r, gtsummary, nlme

**UPDATED with reproducible example.**
I am trying to use tbl_regression() from the package gtsummary on an object of class gls, produced using package nlme. This code worked some months ago but is now failing; I'm sorry I don't know the last version of R/packages that worked.

Reproducible example:

```
require(ggtree)
require(nlme)
require(geiger)
require(gtsummary)

# Generate tree
tr <- rtree(30)

# Pull out tip labels
tips <- tr$tip.label

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1)

# Create data frame with random numbers
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=60, min=1, max=100), nrow=30))

# Combine with tip labels
df <- cbind(tips, df)

# Define column names
names(df) <- c("Name", "A", "B")

# Generate gls model
dfmodel <- gls(A ~ B, correlation = corBrownian(phy = tr, form = ~Name),
    data = df, method = "ML")

# View model object
class(dfmodel)
summary(dfmodel)

# Try getting tbl_regression() summary
tbl_regression(dfmodel, intercept = T)
```

This yields:

```
> class(dfmodel)
[1] "gls"
> summary(dfmodel)
Generalized least squares fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: A ~ B 
  Data: df 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  305.7642 309.9678 -149.8821

Correlation Structure: corBrownian
 Formula: ~Name 
 Parameter estimate(s):
numeric(0)

Coefficients:
               Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 61.20839 23.918463  2.559044  0.0162
B           -0.30495  0.203606 -1.497732  0.1454

 Correlation: 
  (Intr)
B -0.43 

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-0.97003510 -0.29480997  0.08510202  0.63636176  1.13954597 

Residual standard error: 50.54416 
Degrees of freedom: 30 total; 28 residual
> 
> # Try getting tbl_regression() summary
> tbl_regression(dfmodel, intercept = T)
! `broom::tidy()` failed to tidy the model.
✔ `tidy_parameters()` used instead.
ℹ Add `tidy_fun = broom.helpers::tidy_parameters` to quiet these messages.
✖ Unable to identify the list of variables.

This is usually due to an error calling `stats::model.frame(x)`or `stats::model.matrix(x)`.
It could be the case if that type of model does not implement these methods.
Rarely, this error may occur if the model object was created within
a functional programming framework (e.g. using `lappy()`, `purrr::map()`, etc.).
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

R and package versions from sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] geiger_2.0.11   phytools_1.9-16 maps_3.4.1      ape_5.7-1       gtsummary_1.7.2 nlme_3.1-162    ggtree_3.8.2
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you are not dealing with a `gls()` object after you run `stepAIC()`. Please update your post with a reproducible example.